# DataTables jQuery - custom sort arrows

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm trying to change the sort arrows on the jQuery version of DataTables (https://datatables.net/). I want to accomplish this without bringing in the stylesheet and other files. The default uses a purple arrow, which doesn't work with my color scheme. I was reading that they are png, so I can't just change the color. Is there some HTML/CSS that I can add to change the arrows to my own icons?

Comment: `Is there some HTML/CSS that I can add to change the arrows to my own icons?` yes there is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dominik I've tried changing the background-image for "table.dataTable thead .sorting", "table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc", "table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone in the future who will need this, in order to change the sort arrows you have to create an internal style. Since DataTables uses !important, you can't change it in an external stylesheet (that I know of).

Add this to the head or body of the html file:

```
<style>
table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
background-image: url(.....) !important;
}
</style>
```